# How to unit-test static method in interface with Android Test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, java-8, junit4, android-testing

How to unit-test interface's static method with instrumentation test?

I tried testing(Android Test) with following code; simplified for explanation.

But AndroidStudio said "Empty test suite."

In the case same code with local unit test(it meeans test code is located in test/java), test result was **GREEN**.

Why does only android-test fail?

and how to write android-test code for interface static method?

test target:

```
public interface SampleInterface {
    static String methodA(){
        return "foobar";
    }
}
```

test code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SampleInterfaceTest {
    @Test
    public void methodA() {
        Assert.assertThat(SampleInterface.methodA(), is("foobar"));
    }
}
```

message.

```
Started running tests
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'
Empty test suite.
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project? `Build > Clean Project`. I sometimes get this when testing normal methods too - this is more to do with the test class than the fact you're testing `static` methods

Comment: Unfortunately, result showed same message...